# Pass Upper Boundary to Array

Tags: vba, excel

I want my macro to read from a list of phone numbers on another sheet, count the rows, then construct an array from A1:An...from the row count. The array will always start at A1.

```
Dim lrow As Variant 

lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim PhonesArray as Variant

PhonesArray = " [A1:A" & lrow & "].Value2
```

I'm unable to pass the upper boundary (lrow) to PhonesArray.

it should run as

```
PhonesArray = [A1:A**40**].Value2
```

The lrow variable is calculating correctly, but I'm unable to pass it into the array construction. A static range works as expected. Any assistance is greatly appreciated and apologies in advance if the issue has been addressed before. I was unable to find a solution through my search.

Comment: `[square brackets]` are good enough for getting quick results out of the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G), but they are a shorthand syntax for `Application.Evaluate`, i.e. much slower than "normal code" would be. If you want to get a `Range` from a `Worksheet`, get that `Worksheet` and pull its `Range` property, e.g. `Sheet1.Range("A1:A40")`. `Application.Evaluate` / square brackets work off whatever sheet is active, which is bug-prone, and frail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You require `Range("a1:a" & lRow).value2` I believe

Comment: I used your example verbatim and it worked perfectly. Your very quick response is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

In general, it's a bad idea to refer to your cells with the `[A1]` type shorthand and it doesn't support being put together in a string like that. Use `Range()` instead and you'll have a few options:

- `Range("A1:A" & lRow)`
- `Range("A1").Resize(lrow,1)`

Given the code you've provided, I'd scrap the `lrow` variable and just use this:

```
Dim PhonesArray As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    PhonesArray = Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value2
End With
```

Comment: Just a mention that the second method is only valid without adjustment if the range starts in the first row.

Comment: @Jeeped, I realised that too - couldn't decide whether to omit it for that reason but just left it in the end. At least if OP plays around with `Resize` they might learn something new :)

Answer (score 1):

I generally prefer to reference the parent worksheet and define the start and stop of the range with cells.

```
Dim lrow As long, phonesArray as variant

with worksheets("your_worksheet's_name")
    lrow = .cells(.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    phonesArray = .range(.cells(1, "A"), .cells(lrow, "A")).Value2
    debug.print lbound(phonesArray, 1) & " to " & ubound(phonesArray, 1)
    debug.print lbound(phonesArray, 2) & " to " & ubound(phonesArray, 2)
end with
```

Comment: I like the consistency of using `Cells` for the start and end, it reads nicely.